# How to test renewable subscriptions (App Store)

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing auto renewable subscriptions in my app and I wonder if there is a way to simulate when a subscription period runs out and a new transaction is created.

The app is connected to a online service that always keeps track of the users and if they have "premium access" or not. As understand i, there are two ways to detect when a transaction is made.

1. The app is launched and updatedTransactions: is called in my PaymentObserver as a SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored. I then, from the app, send this information to the server which updates the subscription.
2. I regularly check the App Store API and compare the "latest receipt" with the one in my database. If there is a new one, a transaction has been made and I extend the subscription.

Either way, I need to simulate that the subscription period runs out and a new transaction is made by the App Store. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need to simulate this? I think you'll find that in the sandbox, the subscription lengths are made very short so that all you have to do is get a cup of coffee or something and they will expire and then you can test what happens.

the amount of time varies depending on the length of the subscription, but I think the 7 day subscription expires in just a few minutes in the sandbox.

Comment: right, a 7 days subscription last *3 minutes* in the sandbox env.

Comment: One caveat: Subscriptions will only auto renew 5 times. After that if you purchase they will no longer auto-renew. You have to create a new test user to do it!

Answer (score 7):

The sandbox environment automatically simulates subscription renewal.  1 year subscriptions will renew every 1 hour. 1 month subscriptions appear to renew every 5-6 minutes.

Each subscription appears to renew 5x.  At that point, the subscription is cancelled.  Each renewal triggers a restored transaction sent to the client app.

This is all based on my experience. I cannot find any official documentation for it from Apple.

Comment: This is all documented here (developer login required):  http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Actually the renewal doesn't seem to work in Sandbox. It looks like you're always into the buying process. Auto-renewal is supposed to be "shadowed" as AppStore will automatically re-conduct it until the user explicitly "cancel" it. In the Sandbox, each 5 minutes you have to purchase again.

Finally, there's a bug in the "You Already purchased that in-app" as it is supposed to send a proper transaction but it just sends an Error code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I experience the renewal in the Sandbox to be very unpredictable. Sometimes it works as described, sometimes it works very differently, sometimes it doesn't work at all (saying that as a developer with an app in store that actually uses In-App-Purchases with autorenewable subscriptions, apparently successfully in production).
Just at the moment I have a monthly subscription in the sandbox that has an original purchase date from 27 hours back and an expiry date of three hours back. I really wonder how you are supposed to test this if the responses are absurd like that.